# deploying my app to heroku with node and it is giving me cannot Get /

Tags: javascript, node.js

**These are my `app.js` code**

```
    const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port  = process.env.PORT || 5000
const source = (path.join(__dirname, './src/'))
console.log(source)
const getSource = app.use(express.static(source))
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port ' + port)
})
```

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "calculategp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/PelumiWeb/PelumiGpCalculator.git"
  },
  "author": "Oluwapelumi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/PelumiWeb/PelumiGpCalculator/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/PelumiWeb/PelumiGpCalculator#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

i tried running it locally and it worked, i only get this error when i am deploying to heroku.

and i've also created a Procfile file that contains `web:node` `app.js`
but it still didn't work.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why things might not work when going from local dev to a server. Plugins like "papertrail" can be useful for debugging on Heroku. Its possible that you missed something in your setup such as DNS or environment variables

Comment: Okay, how can i install "papertrails" ?

Comment: and how can i use it to debug, is it just by adding it to my project?

Comment: In the resources page on the web portal, just search for the add ons you want and add them to your project. Papertrail lets you read your console logs